# Why doesn't Mathematica evaluate this simple integral involving the logarithm function?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I am trying to perform the following integral in Mathematica:

```
Assuming[a \[Element] Re && y \[Element] Re && r > 0, 
 Integrate[Log[x^2 + a^2], {x, 0, y}]]
```

But Mathematica takes forever to work on this even though there is a well-defined analytic expression for this integral for the given parameter values. Why does this happen?

Eventually, I want to evaluate related but more complicated integrals such as:

```
Integrate[Log[(x + y)^2 m^2 + x*y*q^2], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1 - x}]
```

Could you please help me resolve the issue with the simpler integral and then suggest how I could proceed to do the more complex one? Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

You have a syntax error. The domain of real numbers is written `Reals`, not Re. `Re` stands for the real part of a complex number.  With this change:

```
Assuming[a \[Element] Reals && y \[Element] Reals && r > 0, 
 Integrate[Log[x^2 + a^2], {x, 0, y}]]

(*2 y (-1 + Log[Abs[y]])*)
```